# Get a list of specific values from a C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Let's say I have a C# dictionary with `Enum` values like this:

```
public enum TileType
{
    Source,
    Horizontal,
    Vertical
}

Dictionary<Tile, TileType> tiles = new Dictionary<Tile, TileType>();
```

... And later I want to retrieve all key value pairs from the dict that are for example of `value = TileType.Horizontal` but without using a `foreach` loop.

How do I retrieve them without a loop? I have no doubt it's possible with LINQ. Can somebody give me a hint how to write the LINQ for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var horizontals = tiles.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == TileType.Horizontal).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @BadmintonCat note that this is still executing a loop, it's just it's not in *your* code...

Comment: @AakashM - Which I think must be implicit in this question. There's no other way to get the values - even if you finally got down to machine code.

Comment: Also, only evaluate the LINQ expression when you are ready to view the results.  The `ToList()` call will evaluate the IEnumerable.Where expression and pull the data into memory.  However, its sometimes better to wait until you are ready to use the data.  This way you can perform more queries (orderby, selects, joins) on the data set without actually pulling in the data.  In this example the impact is small, but when working with large data-sets, the early evaluation of the set can cause performance issues (esp in queryables using the Entity Framework)

Comment: @zackery.fix - That advice is only half of the story. The opposite problem can also occur - if you build several queries based on a single query and then try to access each of these queries then the single underlying query is run several times. You could causing performance issues by **delaying** execution.

Comment: @zackery.fix - Even worse, if you continue to build upon an EF query you can end up causing the single C# query to end up being split into many many database queries. The circumstances of when to call `.ToList()` (or any other operator which forces evaluation) needs to be carefully considered if it is **too early** or **too late**. There is no rule that works all of the time.

Comment: Yes, but the general case is that you have some sort of control flow in your application.  I have used EF and IEnumerable LINQ queries on enormous sets of data and never run into this problem.  For one, you don't execute multiple queries derived from the same query; you only refine the query you are working with until you are ready to evaluate it.  This problem only occurs when you don't use a unit-of-work approach or you keep passing around the same query to perform multiple sub-queries against it.  I am familiar with this issue, but its completely avoidable with good code design.

Comment: +2  However, indubitably noted.

Comment: One short thing: What do I have to do to use `ToDictionary` instead of `ToList`? I've tried `tiles.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == TileType.Horizontal).ToDictionary(pair => tiles)` but that gives me a dictionary containing dictionaries.

Comment: @BadmintonCat - You should really ask a new question, but you need `tiles.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == TileType.Horizontal).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you sir! I was just about to write a loop! I know it should've been a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
tiles.Where(x => x.Value == TileType.Horizontal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its like this:

```
var filteredTiles = tiles.Where(x=>x.Value == TileType.Horizontal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like that:

```
tiles.Where(t => t.value == TileType.Horizontal).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (var item in tiles.Where(t => t.Value == TileType.Horizontal))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
 }
```